# How can I determine if a string contains a character and then a number?

Tags: c++

I'm making a command line battleship game in C++ and need to be able to determine if a string entered by the player contains a character (A - J) and then a number (1 - 14), which will represent the coordinates of the ship currently being entered.  Is there a way to do this without using regular expressions (simply because regex seems unnecessary for a problem such as this; if it's the best solution then that's perfectly fine)?

I've tried using things such as `get` for the character and then `getline` to read the next characters, but that seems very inefficient.

Comment: Use getline to grab the input into a std::string.  Then you can parse and validate the contents.  Validating the letter seems straight forward - it's a single character that has to be in a certain range.

Comment: You can, of course, write a custom matcher for the regex `^[A-J][1-9]|(1[0-4])$`. It would be a state machine with just a few states. Alternatively, you can just read a `char` followed by an `int` (you can use `std::noskipws` if you don't want to allow space between the `char` and the `int` and, if reading that is successful, check that the values are in range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
bool validShipCoords(char input_char, int num) {
    /* Check character from A-J or a-j, and number 
       less or equal to 14*/
    return ((input_char >= 65 && input_char <= 75)
        || (input_char >= 97 && input_char <= 107))
        && num <= 14;
}

int main()
{
    string shipCoords;
    cout<<"Enter coordinates" <<endl;
    getline(cin, shipCoords);
    string subCoordNum = shipCoords.substr(1); // Get the number
    int coordnum = std::stoi(subCoordNum); // change to int

    //shipCoords.at(0) is the letter
    if (validShipCoords(shipCoords.at(0), coordnum)) {
        cout << shipCoords << " is valid coordinates" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "invalid coordinates" <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because this code is bad. It invokes undefined behaviour when an empty string is passed, uses magic numbers instead of char literals and misuses `endl`.